# php code for mysql connection not executing

Tags: xml, validation

The following is source of one html file I made containing PHP-MySQL connection and data retrieval code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "pass123";
$dbname = "mydb1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT impath, facenm, descp FROM fac_tab";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<br> impath: ". $row["impath"]. " - Name: ". $row["facenm"]. "     " . $row["descp"] . "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

but when I open the above .htm file in Mozilla Firefox browser keeping my system's MySQL server open, I do not get the data retrieved from the mydb1 database but instead get the following display by the browser:

```
connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } $sql = "SELECT impath, facenm, descp FROM fac_tab"; $result = $conn->query($sql); if ($result->num_rows > 0) { // output data of each row while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { echo "
impath: ". $row["impath"]. " - Name: ". $row["facenm"]. " " . $row["descp"] . "
"; } } else { echo "0 results"; } $conn->close(); ?>
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any localhost server like xampp??

---

> PHP is a server side language. It isn't a static language like **HTML, JavaScript and CSS**. **PHP** is installable to server but the other's are installed by built in. So, you have to use any of **localhost server** or any hosting that support PHP and MySQL.

Change your file's extension name

---

You should rename your filename from **.htm to .php**. Server response of any scripts through it's extension name. Like `.js` couldn't content `css` codes.

So, you can fix your problem by doing this two things:

1. Install a localhost server,
2. Change Extension from `.html` to `.php`.

Comment: What is a "folt"?

Comment: I do not have xampp, wamp etc. installed in my system. My platform is Windows 7 64-bit. I did not have MySQL installed so I downloaded the Windows MySQL installer and installed MySQL Server and MySQL utilities and demos and examples skipping other stuff of the offline 300+ MB installer and then using NetBeans IDE created the "mydb1" MySQL database and then using NetBeans IDE's SQL editor created the table "fac_tab" and added one record and then keeping NetBeans open and MySQL server connected but database connection disconnected I opened the above HTML file in Mozilla Firefox browser.

Comment: I changed the extension to php and opened in the browser but the output is same. I got the above code from w3schools.com website and just wanted to learn how PHP-MySQL works. I am trying to learn this for using in one of my websites. I do not have Apache installed in my system. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @AlokChakrabarty 
Hi, Alok. You have written an php file with php functions. PHP is not a static language it is an server-side languages. In case of exciting php codes you must need a php server. So, you have to install xampp, wamp or anything else.
Or else the php code won't work.
Install a php server and tell me if it don't work.

Comment: @AlokChakrabarty 
You should thik or mark as best any answer which helps you or solute your problem according to StackOverFlow rules.

Comment: @meagar I am not so much good in speaking English. Also my point is very less (1).

Comment: @meagar I am not so much strong in English. Notice Alok isn't marking anyone's answer as best or talking about this question.

Answer (score 0):

change file extension from .html to .php

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this. It did not work.

Comment: I do not have Apache installed in my system.

Comment: then you have to install the xampp software that provide local host server functanility